# Is it possible to use a global variable as volatile in a part of code and non-volatile in the other part

Tags: c++, volatile

In B.h

```
volatile int y;

Class B {
    fooB(int);
}
```

In A.cpp

```
foo (int x) {
    return 2*x;
}

foo(y);  // Here is the issue
```

When I tried to do this I faced a compilation problem, given that I can't change the signature of `foo()` function. Is there any solution to my question in title?

Comment: Is it `B::foo` in A.cpp or just `foo`? If you declare a function, then of course it can differ from the method of `class B`. Or what do you want?

Comment: I corrected it, it is just foo.

Comment: Can you please Show the error?

Comment: What is the point of a volatile funtion argument that is not passed by reference?

Comment: The error is about that foo() function does not take a volatile variable as input, but when i correct it as this: foo(volatile int), it works, but i have not.

Comment: Sorry @MackieMesser, i didn't understand you question. In fact, y is used as volatile in class B but not in class A.

Comment: Well, then you got your answer, you can't pass a non-volatile variable.

Comment: I need a solution if possible. Another way for example? That makes same work as volatile?

Comment: The variable must be declared volatile in all source files. Can't you create a new non-volatile variable, initialize it with the contents of the volatile variable and then use the new variable instead?

Comment: It didn't work, this is the erro:

error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'volatile IARM_STATUS' to 'IARM_STATUS'

Comment: What type is IARM_STATUS? Is it a pointer or a reference? In that case the answer is NO, you cannot drop the volatile qualifier under any circumstances. Please check what the volatile qualifier actually means, so you understand the issues at hand.

Comment: I don't think your example code matches your description. Calling a `foo(int)` with a volatile int works without any problems. Of what relevance to the problem are `class B` and `B::fooB`?

Comment: The error, exactly, is here:

IARM_RESULT res = iarm_get_status(iarm->g_hRobot, &current_status);

error C2664: 'iarm_get_status' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'volatile IARM_STATUS *' to 'IARM_STATUS *'

Comment: try to explicitly cast `volatile int *` to `int *`. the previous error shows that foo(int) is not the problem because you are passing `y` **as a value**. but in iarm_get_status() you are passing `y` **as a pointer reference**. if you are doing this use casting.

Comment: i hope you are specifying the type for foo in definition and declaration.